# When JavaScript object literal nested, what the this is?

Tags: javascript

I have a object `a`:

```
var a = {
    b: {
        f1: function(){console.log('in a.b.f1')}
    },
    c: {
        _this: this,
        f2: function(){this._this.b.f1()}
    }
}
```

then, I found the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'f1' of undefined`

How should I call `a.b.f1()` in `a.c.f2`?

Comment: See my post and let me know if you can't understand something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) - whether it's nested or not does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the question, use `a.b.f1()`.

By default, `this` refers to the object which owns the function. If the function is "free", `this` refers to the global `window` object. If `this` is not wrapped inside a function, it refers to `window` as well.

```
// "this" is window
function f() { /* "this" is "window" */ }
var o = {};
o.f = function () { /* "this" is "o" */ }
o.child = {};
o.child.f = function () { /* "this" is "o.child" */ }
```

Knowing this and considering your code, we can say that `this` does not refer to `a` since it's not contained in a function owned by `a`. As a workaround, you could simply replace `this` with `a` :

```
var a = {};
a.b = {
    f1: function () { console.log('in a.b.f1'); }
};
a.c = {
    parent: a,
    f2: function () { this.parent.b.f1(); }
};
```

Notice that you can "redirect" `this` to another object using `call()` or `apply()` :

```
o.child.f.call(o); // "this" is now "o" inside of "o.child.f"
```

Comment: [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is also useful for creating functions that will always have `this` bound to a specific object.

Comment: Thank you, but in the console I found that:`a.c  
Object {parent: undefined, f2: function}`